# List Comprehension reset the iterator variable?

Tags: python

Is it possible to reset `x` in

```
lis[3, 3, 4, 5]

test = [(tes(x)) for x in range (0, len(lis)) if lis[x] == "abc"]
```

or maybe instead use some while loop. The thing is I'd like to run this comprehension list on my `lis` once I'm done, and not just one iteration.

say that I want to decrement each variable in the list.

```
lis[3, 3, 4, 5]

lis[2, 2, 3, 4]

lis[1, 1, 2, 3]

lis[0, 0, 1, 2]
```

and then stop once the first hits zero.

Comment: you should explain what you are looking for as output

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: can you add an actual runnable example? There are numerous ways to do it but how you do it depends on what you are actually doing

Comment: @JonCode And is your actual issue really this simple? If so, why not just subtract all elements using the first element in the list (this can be done in a list comprehension) .

Comment: @AnandSKumar No it's not this simple, I just wanted to do if there was a simple method for just reseting x everytime it appends to the list. I just tried to make an example, so I can figure the implementation out myself

Answer (score 2):

You could `cycle` the list until you hit your condition, here we break on the first value hitting `0`:

```
from itertools import cycle

lis = [3, 3, 4, 5]
for ind, ele in enumerate(iter(lambda: next(cycle(lis)), 0)):
    lis[ind % len(lis)] -= 1

print(lis)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: +1 for using cycle() which looks to be just the right recipe for infinite list looping. But the resulting construction iter-lambda-next-cycle is a bit less appealing.

Comment: @LiMar,  if you did not use iter lambda you would not be able to use the for loop with enumerate, the alternative is a count variable and and if with break, I prefer using enumerate

Comment: This prints `[0, 1, 2, 3]` when starting with `[3, 3, 4, 5]`, since you stop half way through the list. This is different than the example given in the question.

Comment: @bas this stops at the first zero as per the OPs instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to decrease all members of the list by 1 until the smaller member(s) achieve value of 0.

```
def decrease_list(lis):
     def stop():
         raise Exception("Stop")
     try:
         while True:
             lis=[e - 1 if e>1 else stop() for e in lis]
     except:
         pass
     return lis
```

Let's test it:

```
In [35]: lis=[20, 12, 11, 10]

In [36]: decrease_list(lis)
Out[36]: [10, 2, 1, 0]

In [33]: lis =  [20, 12, 10, 10]

In [34]: decrease_list(lis)
Out[34]: [10, 2, 0, 0]
```